# Split a vector element in R

Tags: r, vector, transactions, apriori, arules

i have vector in this format with just one element:

```
t1
     [,1]                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
[1,] "<meta','name','description','content','Compre','ingressos','para','FEIRA','DIGITAL','EXPO','SP','2022','em','SÃ£o','Paulo','dia','14','de','julho.','Confira','os','melhores','eventos','de','2022','na','Sympla!>\n"
```

and i need to split this into a vector with many elements, which are separated by comma, the purpose is to create a transactional dataframe to use with arules.

Could you help me? Thanks

Comment: This looks like a list. You could use `unlist()` as in `t2 = unlist(t1)`

Comment: `strsplit(t2, ', ')`

Comment: thansk but none of them gave an array of strings..another help°

Answer (score 0):

I think it is matrix 1X1 so try

```
strsplit(t1[1] , ",")
```

Comment: > strsplit(t1[1] , ",")
[[1]]
 [1] "<meta'"        "'name'"        "'description'" "'content'"     "'Compre'"      "'ingressos'"  
 [7] "'para'"        "'FEIRA'"       "'DIGITAL'"     "'EXPO'"        "'SP'"          "'2022'"       
[13] "'em'"          "'SÃ£o'"        "'Paulo'"       "'dia'"         "'14'"          "'de'"         
[19] "'julho.'"      "'Confira'"     "'os'"          "'melhores'"    "'eventos'"     "'de'"         
[25] "'2022'"        "'na'"          "'Sympla!>\n"

Comment: what is your desired output ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a single string in a 1x1 matrix. If you want to extract the words into a vector, with the quotes and angle brackets removed, you can do:

```r
gsub('<|>|\n|\\!', "", strsplit(c(t1), "','")[[1]])
#>  [1] "meta"        "name"        "description" "content"     "Compre"     
#>  [6] "ingressos"   "para"        "FEIRA"       "DIGITAL"     "EXPO"       
#> [11] "SP"          "2022"        "em"          "SÃ£o"        "Paulo"      
#> [16] "dia"         "14"          "de"          "julho."      "Confira"    
#> [21] "os"          "melhores"    "eventos"     "de"          "2022"       
#> [26] "na"          "Sympla"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>